# Compare count before and after dynamic date in R

Tags: r

My company throws events to increase engagement on the platform. I've already joined the data frame for events with the engagement data. I'm trying to measure the performance of these events to see if engagement is increasing but I can't seem to figure out how to compare the count of pre-event observations with post-event observations. If someone can point out how to limit a count by the date in the data frame that would likely resolve my problem.

Here's an example of the head of my data.

```
ID  Factor_date event_date  event_name
1   12/2/2016   10/24/2016  Party1
2   11/28/2016  10/24/2016  Party4
3   12/1/2016   4/28/2016   Party6
4   11/25/2016  10/25/2016  Party3
5   11/28/2016  3/20/2017   Social awareness event1
6   12/2/2016   12/6/2016   Party1
```

We have an ID of the user. The factor_date is the date of engagement on the platform and event date is the date we held the event. I'm new to R.

Comment: Is ID 5 your reference event or just an event for the user? What have you tried? What problem does your current solution have? I feel you need to provide more details.

Comment: what is your expected  output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dates are always a bit of a pain, but the tidyverse packages help a lot. My example uses a function from the lubridate package. You can install just lubridate, but I recommend installing all the tidyverse packages, they're quite useful.

I believe you want to count how many engagements happened before and how many after the event, is that correct? I also provide a code to let you know how long before or after, this can also be useful.

```
library(tibble)
library(lubridate)

ID <- 1:6
#-- using proper date formating from lubridate
Factor_date <- mdy(c("12/2/2016", "11/28/2016",
                     "12/1/2016", "11/25/2016", "11/28/2016",
                     "12/2/2016"))
event_date <- mdy(c("10/24/2016", "10/24/2016", "4/28/2016", "10/25/2016",
                    "3/20/2017", "12/6/2016"))
event_name <- c("Party1", "Party4", "Party6", "Party3",
                "Social awareness event1", "Party1")

#-- reconstruct data into a tibble
data <- tibble(ID, Factor_date, event_date, event_name)

#-- recover the time difference in a difftime object
engagement_time <- Factor_date - event_date

post_event_count <- sum(engagement_time > 0)
pre_event_count <- sum(engagement_time <= 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for helping an R noob! This did the trick for me, perfectly.

Comment: Now I need to find the function that will show both pre and post while also grouping by ID, that would be fantastic. Your help so far is greatly appreciated though. Thanks again!